# Existence of lim sup/lim inf for bounded positive sequences

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Is it true that a sequence that is non-negative and bounded always have a convergent lim sup or lim inf ?

Comment: I think you may want to google "Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem". In fact, the sequence doesn't need to be non-negative, just bounded, for that thing to be true.

Comment: And why should it be bounded?

Comment: @Jonas Otherwise it isn't true. I'm assuming here the asker meant by "convergent..." in the finite  sense.

Comment: True what? It is just a definition.

Comment: @jonas what's just a definition?  What are you talking about.  {n} isn't bounded and doesn't have a convergent lim sup.

Comment: Never heard of "convergent" limsup. Simply you can defined it *always*, and so the question of whether it converges clearly makes no sense.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to show that for any sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $-C\leq x_n \leq C$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N},$ we have that
$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$ exists and is finite. First note that by definition
$$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sup\limits_{m\geq n}x_m\right).$$
Consider the sequence 
$$(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}:=\left(\sup\limits_{m\geq n}x_m\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}.$$
Then obviously, $y_n\geq y_{n+1},$ so that the sequence $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is monotone decreasing. Moreover, since $x_n\geq -C$ for all $n,$ $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is bounded from below, and so it must converge by
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem .
You can proceed similarly for the $\liminf$.

Comment: You don't need the non-negative part, you just need boundedness from below and from above. If the sequence is non-negative, then obviously it is bounded by 0 from below.